# Div won't 100% width of browser in IE8

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div that I want to fit the full width of any screen so I used this code:

```
.top {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#3d7294;
    width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    z-index:-999;
}
```

But the problem is that I have the rest of my website centered and the "top" div in IE doesn't start from the top left but from the start of the centered div I use for my main content.

[image]

And this is how it looks in Chrome and FF and how it *should* look:

[image]

The only thing I can think that's affecting it is that the my main div has:

```
.all {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

But my "top" div is outside of the "all" div so I wouldn't have thought it would of affected it.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KmSbn/) of my code.

Comment: What `DOCTYPE` are you using?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> It's the standard that Dreamweaver chose. I'm never sure what DOCTYPE's to use

Comment: You need to set up a position to your body (position relative). Currently on IE, they think that your parent div is .all, so it take 100% of all.

Comment: Which IE version(s) are you testing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem.

I added `left:0px;` to my "top" div

```
.top {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#3d7294;
    width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    z-index:-999;
    left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have **DOCTYPE** at the top of your code. Else include these height and width for your div.

```
var dWidth = wWidth * 0.65;
var wHeight = $(window).height();
var dHeight = wHeight * 0.65;
```

Comment: This will adjust the div to fit according to your window size, irrespective of the screen resolution.

Comment: How do you get that 0.65?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

**Css**

```
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin: 0px;
background-color: #f9fbfd;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

html {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Can't test it, I'm on mac

Comment: uhm, if you set up the html with to 100%, does it change some thing? I update my css

Comment: -1 Why have you used `td, th`? Why have you set the font, and background? What relevance do these have to the question?

Comment: Well spotted jumpingcode, mistake from copy and pasting jsfidle